# Programmatically modify web.config for a self-hosted service (not via changes to applicationHost.config)

Tags: vb.net, wcf, ssl, iis

I'm stuck on something I should probably move on from but it's driving me nuts...
I can programmatically update SSL certificate info for a self-hosted WCF service using:

```vb
Dim config As Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration = _
  serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration
site.Bindings.Clear()
Dim binding = site.Bindings.Add(ipport, cert.GetCertHash, store.Name)
serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

and can also change sections of my local web.config using a known file path starting with:

```vb
Dim cfg As System.Configuration.Configuration = _
  System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(ConfigFileMap, target)
```

but if I try to drill down to system.webServer/security/access using:

```vb
Dim accessSection = cfg.GetSection("system.webServer/security")
```

I get Nothing/null and further digging helpfully produces this status for the section "System.Configuration.IgnoreSection", which apparently indicates that System.Configuration doesn't want to play nice with that specific piece - even though it's not denied access in applicationHost as near as I can tell.

On the other hand, if I try to use Microsoft.Web.Administration I can only figure out how to make the change to applicationHost.config, not to the local web.config.

The only thing that seems to want to put the client certificate requirement (sslFlags setting) in the local web.config is IIS Manager (which also doesn't show the setting correctly if it is located in the applicationHost.config)

Obviously there are all sorts of ways to do this but I can't believe there isn't a simple dot net way (other than editing the xml). Does anyone know what the heck I am doing wrong?

Comment: You do realize that if you modify the web.config at runtime, the application will restart?

Comment: I want it to - it's not a public facing web site. Besides, if the SSL cert expired it wouldn't work anyway :-)

Comment: You could find yourself in an infinite loop, however - start the app, modify the config file, app restarts, modifies the config file, repeat.  Unless you have logic to prevent it from entering this condition.

Comment: It's an admin control panel/windows forms app to provide a one-stop gui for adjusting things like ssl thumbnails for expiring certificates, changing client certificate settings, email notification parameters and so forth for a custom web service. The only time it's run is when a manual restart is required, none of the standard caveats apply. It is intended to avoid individually editing multiple web.configs by hand is all.

Answer (score 0):

Doh!!! Apparently I need to learn to read the manual (although MS doesn't make it easy).

You can simply do:

```vb
Using serverManager As New ServerManager
    Dim config As Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration = _
      serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("site name", "/application")
    Dim accessSection As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection = _
      config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access")
    accessSection("sslFlags") = "Ssl,SslRequireCert"
    serverManager.CommitChanges()
End Using
```

Retroactively obvious link: [Relevant StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825883/trying-to-read-web-config-file-for-an-iis-site-from-a-windows-service)